# Access object wrapped in curly braces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ancestry

I have this object that is returned from from a query using some Ancestry Gem methods:

```
 @category = ItemsCategory.find(params[:id_and_name]).subtree.arrange
```

This is the result:

```
category = {#<ItemsCategory id: 16, name: "Coffee Tables", created_at: "2014-04-02 19:50:26", updated_at: "2014-06-03 21:03:03", title_tag: nil, description_tag: nil, ancestry: "144/1/7">=>{}}
```

How can I get to the different keys? If I say @category.id I get @category has no method id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is a hash, with the key being the `ItemsCategory` object you are trying to access. Notice the `=>{}}` at the end of the line. This is because your `ItemsCategory` has no child instances associated with it.

If you still want to access this, do as so:

```
@category.keys.first.id # => 16
```